# Cannot see echo message but my localhost works

Tags: php

This is my very first php code and I can't seem to get it to work. (I'm using Eclipse)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

    echo 'Hello World!';
    $txt = "I <3 you!";
    $num = 19;

?>  
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it (http://localhost/Assignment3.0/index.php), I get:

Not Found

**The requested URL /Assignment3.0/index.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80**

But when I run this (http://localhost/), I get:

**It works!
This is the default web page for this server.**

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

So what could be the problem? Where's my "Hello World!"?

Do I need to add my file into some sort of folder under localhost or something?

Also, for Stackoverflow formatting, how do I start a new line w/o adding a blank line in between?

Comment: You need to figure out where your DocumentRoot is pointed.  You are likely not putting your index.php in the right spot.  As far as starting a newline without adding a blank line, put two spaces at the end of the line go to the next line.  The two spaces will render as a newline.

Comment: first your code is not properly nested, </html> should follow </body>

Comment: Your HTML code is wrong </html>
</body>
 Change it to </body>
</html>

Comment: That's not really a programming question... are the files in your webroot? If not, how should Apache know which file it should serve for that path? As for editing: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: What is the name of your application folder? Make it sure that you are not making mistake in Case sensitive way

Comment: How do I put files into "webroot"?
(btw I fixed the </html></body> order and changed to 3_0)

Comment: Maybe I need a symbolic link?

Comment: @Sean Accept the correct answers so that others can refer to it :)

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Can you help me track down my problem a little bit more? (You definitely found a big bug for me though. Thant would take me a long time to find it)

Comment: I simply created a file in Eclipse and ran it. Should I add my project "Assignment3_0" to the localhost? If so, how?

Comment: btw I WILL accept your answer. Dont you worry ;j

Answer (score 3):

Never use a period `.` for naming directories `Assignment3.0`, use underscores `_` instead `Assignment3_0` and it should work for you..

And btw close your `html` tag after `body` tag

Comment: I guess it's getting interpreted as a file name - `Assignment3`.`0/index.php`... nice catch, I would never have thought of that.

Comment: @WesleyMurch my localhost accepts this but I prefer not to use it ;)

Comment: Mine does too, maybe that's not the issue.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Strange, and btw that was the issue, he solved it ;)